# Spring active profil for specific app in Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Is it possible to set an spring.profiles.active for a specific webapp in tomcat server ? Not by JAVA_OPTS or catalina.properties.

And is it possible to specify an application configuration file outside my war file ? 
I have to deploy the app in production without know the application-prod.yml params.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes and yes, with little search on spring boot you'll find.

Comment: Need more info plz